# Getting textfield contents from AJAX'd form

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using AJAX to fetch comments dynamically. This DIV which is hidden is filled with the comments and a form and then made visible. The form is used to add new comments to the currently viewed comments list (back via AJAX).

I want the user to be able to view the comments in the DIV and then add comments to the DIV from the DIV itself.

Everything works, except that I cannot get the contents of the textfield of the comments.

I have `$('#submit_comment').live('click', function(e) ...` for detecting the AJAX form submit button. This works. I just can't get the string in the text box... it is very annoying, I have tried many methods like `var comment = $('#new_comment').val();' - this doesn't work.

My HTML includes the following:

```
<form id="new_comment" name="new_comment" method="get" action="comments.php">
                <input type="hidden" id="trackID" value="' . $track . '">
                <input type="text" size="25" id="new_comment_text" /><span style="text-align:right">
                <input type="submit" value="Comment" id="submit_comment"/></span>
            </form>
```

It is echo'd from comments.php and all held inside a floating DIV.

How can I get the contents of the textfield from an AJAX DIV form??

Here is the full AJAX call:

```
$('#submit_comment').live('click', function(e) {


        e.preventDefault();

        var comment = $('#new_comment_text').val();
        alert(comment);

        if (comment != '') {

            $('#loading').show();
            $('#commentsPanel').hide();
            // loading = true

            var track = $('#trackID').val();

            alert(track);
            var data = 'track=' + track + '&isComment=true&comment=' + comment;
            alert(data);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'comment.php',
                type: 'GET',
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                success: function (comments_html) {
                    alert('submit_comment');
                    $('#commentsPanel').html(comments_html);
                    $('#commentsPanel').show();
                    $('#loading').hide();
                }
            });
        } 
        else { 

        }   
    });
```

Comment: Recreate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Tricky when using dynamic content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that your action vs. url don't quite add up because of the missing `s`?

```
form id="new_comment" name="new_comment" method="get" action="comments.php"
```

vs.

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'comment.php',
```

Comment: nvm.. just read your extra comment on the other post... clearly that's what it was.. lol

Answer (score 3):

Your form and text input both have the same id, make the text input element have a unique ID and name.

```
<form id="new_comment" name="new_comment" method="get" action="comments.php">
    <input type="hidden" id="trackID" value="' . $track . '">
    <input type="text" size="25" id="new_comment_text" name="new_comment_text" /><span style="text-align:right">
    <input type="submit" value="Comment" id="submit_comment"/></span>
</form>
```

...

```
var comment = $('#new_comment_text').val(); // Should be the input value.
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/L74hu/

Comment: Actually it's the name that has the same value as id for the text area. I changed all this and it doesn't work anyway.... Any other info?

Comment: @AlexW I don't know what that means, I made a working JSFiddle linked in my answer, is this not what you want?

Comment: I am using an AJAX'd form here (hence the use of `.live()` ) .. I realise .val() normally gets the contents... It;s not working, and I have tested my code thoroughly... confused :(

Comment: @AlexW The use of "ajax'd" is totally fine, your problem arises because the form and input elements have the same id.

Comment: JSFiddle demo... appreciate it... but AJAX is different from static

Comment: @AlexW Okay, sorry it doesn't work for you, if you want to post a little more of the workings of what you are doing then we could probably drive you towards a solution. But the impact between dynamic and static should be a trivial change.

Comment: @Quinten - I've added the full AJAX function. Any guidance appreciated!

Comment: Why is JS so annoying?? It's also fun but... annoying!

Comment: @AlexW Aye it really can be both, but I do love it.. I have a question on the code you posted, with your usage of `live` are you adding multiple of the same form to the DOM?.. That could be the cause of all this, might just need to change to use a different selector or an iterative ID.

Comment: In the end my problem was completely stupid. I forgot the 's' on the end of comments.php .. works now. :)

Answer (score 1):

try sending data in an object like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'comment.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {data:data},
    cache: false,
    success: function (comments_html) {

        alert('submit_comment');
        $('#commentsPanel').html(comments_html);
        $('#commentsPanel').show();
        $('#loading').hide();
    }
});
```

because `$('#new_comment_text').val();` woeked with me in the front end

Answer (score 0):

```
var comment = $('#new_comment').val()
```

Won't work (or probably not) because you have the same ID twice:

```
form  id="new_comment"
input id="new_comment"
```

You should use a different ID and it should be OK